# Creating uncorrelated random variables using diagonalization

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors, covariance, correlation

I have a vector $X$ of random variables with mean $\mu$ and covariance matrix $\Sigma$.

I want to create a vector $Y$ of random variables that are *uncorrelated*, such that the original variables in $X$ are linear combinations of the variables in $Y$.

I remember vaguely that this requires diagonalizing $\Sigma$, but I am not sure about the details.

For concreteness, assume that:

$$
\Sigma = {1\over 36}
\begin{bmatrix}
5 & -1 & -1 & -1 & -1 & -1
\\
-1 & 5 & -1 & -1 & -1 & -1
\\
-1 & -1 & 5 & -1 & -1 & -1
\\
-1 & -1 & -1 & 5 & -1 & -1
\\
-1 & -1 & -1 & -1  & 5 & -1
\\
-1 & -1 & -1 & -1 & -1 & 5
\end{bmatrix}
$$

By diagonalizing $\Sigma$, I get matrices $C$ and $D$ such that $D$ is diagonal and $\Sigma = C D C^{-1}$:

$$
C = \left[\begin{matrix}1 & -1 & -1 & -1 & -1 & -1\\1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0\\1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0\\1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0\\1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1\end{matrix}\right]
\\
D= \left[\begin{matrix}0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\0 & \frac{1}{6} & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\0 & 0 & \frac{1}{6} & 0 & 0 & 0\\0 & 0 & 0 & \frac{1}{6} & 0 & 0\\0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \frac{1}{6} & 0\\0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \frac{1}{6}\end{matrix}\right]
$$
How do I proceed from here - how do I express the vector $X$ as a function of a vector $Y$ where all variables in $Y$ are uncorrelated?

Is there maybe a different way to get uncorrelated variables from correlated ones?

Comment: I assume you mean stochastically independent, not linearly independent?

Comment: @1524 yes, fixed.

Comment: Assuming that $X$ is jointly normal, I would normally de-correlate $X$  by pre-multiplying it by $A$ s.t. $A\Sigma A^T$ is diagonal. Then the fact that for jointly normal varibles, uncorrelatedness implies independence would yield the desired vector of independent variables. But in your case $\Sigma$ does not have full rank (this is called a singular normal distribution) and I'm not sure how this changes the approach.

Comment: You mention $A\Sigma A^T$, but the diagonalization gives you $A\Sigma A^{-1}$ - how are they related?

Comment: Since $\Sigma$ is symmetric, it can be orthogonally diagonalized. That is, you can find an orthogonal matrix $A$ such that $A\Sigma A^{-1}$ is diagonal. Because $A$ is orthogonal, one has $A^{-1}=A^T$